# Entity reference node contents

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have two content types content-type1 and content-type2.
Where I have used content-type1 as a entity reference in content-type2.

I have list of 50 contents in content-type2 and 5 contents in contetn-type2.
now from content-type1 each 10 contents refers to different nodes of contet-type2.
Now on all the 5 nodes of content-type2 I want to create a view block which should display the list of 10 contents which refers that particular node.

Any one can help me how to use contextual filter or relationships for this behavior?

Comment: It would be helpful if your explanation were a little clearer in terms of fields and nodes. It is difficult to tell what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a contextual reference of content-type1 in the view and limit your results to that content type.